# How to detect Client Certificate Authentication request in HTTPWebRequest?

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, http-authentication, client-certificates

I am using `HTTPWebRequest` to access a page which needs Client Certificate!

I am using the following code and everything works!

```
    HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(textBox1.Text);

    X509Certificate2 userCert = SelectClientCertificate();
    if (userCert != null) myReq.ClientCertificates.Add(userCert);

    HttpWebResponse myResp = (HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse();
```

Now here is my problem, since my call `SelectClientCertificate()` shows a Dialog to let the user select a Certificate, I don't want to show the Dialog if the Server doesn't ask for a Client Authentication! Actually I am looking for the behaviorism of Internet Explorer. If accessing a page for which the server needs a user client authentication, you get the Certificate select dialog shown otherwise not!

I looked at the `AuthenticationManager` but I am not sure if I really need to register my own AuthenticationModule! so any hint for me?

I also checked the the `StatusCode` for 403 or 403.7 but the server for now that I am working with, will also return 200 in case of missing Certificate, with content saying that I am not authorized!

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution for this issue ?

Comment: Hi, I'm also interested in the solution if you have one.

Comment: I have the same question.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you want to check what the server wants? It the request runs over https, just ask for certificate.

If I remember well, the server is not obliged to anyone for anything. It is the clients' duty to begin the communication with SSL handshake and the client/server exchange their certificates BEFORE any real HTTP communication occurs. There is no way for you to detect if the server "requires" you to provide a certificate. If you try to talk to it, and if you don't start with a cert and if the server wants cert, the server will drop the connection and remain silent, or maybe it will return some random error code.

You can try to early detect if the server tries to do a handshake before trying to create/send a request to it, but you'd have to do it a layer below, at the TCP layer. Try checking the RFCs describing HTTPS negotation or the preable of handshakes, maybe that will help you a little.

Or just try doing a HTTP w/o S request and if it fails, redo with asking for certificate and retry with HTTPS. I think your users will survive it.

Comment: If required server would request the client to send its certificate. Check out mutual authentication in SSL. Your statement is wrong.

Comment: It may sound a bit messed up, because I mixed general answer with hints about what is possible with HttpWebRequest class. The point was, that (AFAIR) HWR class does not expose any "I-Demand-A-Certificate" event or extensibility point. You have to run the request bare, with no certificates and be prepared for its failure (i.e.retry with cert), or you have to provide a certificate early, before first request is sent. Strangely, the same HWR class and rest of framework provides you with extension points that allow you to get to verify the servers' certs on the fly. I dont understand their vision.

Comment: I suppose LocalCertificateSelectionCallback is used in SslStream class. But it is not exposed in HttpWebRequest class. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.localcertificateselectioncallback.aspx

Comment: This is very useful finding! It may be not easy to get to it in the right time, as we'd need to attach the handler after connetion is started but before it internally passes that step. I don't know how to fetch SslStream instance from the HWReq, but I'd guess it is created lazily after start. But I'm pretty sure that by the time of `RemoteCertificateValidationCallback` the stream is already up and running. So, it actually might be possible to attach a dummy 
RemCerValiCbk and then, from within it, hack the SslStream out of the request instance and connect to LocalCertificateSelectionCallback!